# Python RegEx to make '][?][?]' disappear

Tags: python, regex

There are strings in Stack Exchange Markdown that need to be removed (set to null string). I think Python RegEx would be the best solution. Here are the strings:

```
[![male end][1]][1]
[![female end][2]][2]
```

It probably doesn't matter to those familiar with Stack Exchange Markdown but the original markdown above can be found in [this post in Stack Exchange Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/461935/what-are-these-led-power-supply-plugs-called).

Note that `[![` prefix is for a picture link. Other links will be `[[` or even `[` prefix.

---

### End Result

Using accepted answer this code was written:

```py
def parse(self, ln, points):
    """ Parse every word in line. Skipping footer and body links saves:

        Footer:      28 words, 1,727 references,  29,948 bytes.
        Picture:    473 words,   778 references,  24,295 bytes.
        External: 1,234 words, 2,520 references,  70,002 bytes.
        Regular:  1,648 words, 3,824 references, 101,515 bytes.

    """

    # Skip footer lines with two spaces and: '  [1]: https://...'
    if ln.startswith('  ['):
        return

    # remove links so they don't show up in site search dictionary
    ln = re.sub(r'\[!\[.*?\]\[\d+\]\]\[\d+\]', '', ln)  # [![Image][2][2]
    ln = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]\[\d+\]', '', ln)              # [Link name][3]
    ln = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]\(.*?\)', '', ln)              # [Name](https://...)
```

Comment: Is the output you want `male end` and `female end` ?

Comment: What is the output you want here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `male end` and `female end` are optional link names in markdown. So neither are wanted. Simply erase everything between first `[` and last `]`. The words `male`,  `end` and `female` will already occur elsewhere in the body of the SE post. Completely removing links rather than just the prefix and suffix makes more sense. Sorry for changing project scope in mid-stride:(

Comment: So you want to completely remove these two links, from a larger text, is that right?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes completely remove links. Later I will also remove links in the format:`[?????](http?????)` as well. Hopefully I'll be able to figure it out with your answer and no help from others :) BTW I'm simply building a JavaScript Object in Python of all searchable words in SE markdown. Trying to cut out the fluff words...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.sub` to remove each markup tag:

```py
inp = "Hello [![male end][1]][1] World [![female end][2]][2] Goodbye"
output = re.sub(r'\[!\[.*?\]\[\d+\]\]\[\d+\]', '', inp)
print(output)  # Hello  World  Goodbye
```

Comment: I had to revise the question to make it more clear and avoid close votes. Unfortunately that makes your answer not as clear. My apologies

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I have edited my answer with your latest edit.  Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Everything is working great! I've updated the question with the space savings -- about 200K. [If you want to see the search engine in action](https://pippim.github.io/index.html) you can type `[1]` and get 690 results. Of course after refreshing the website you will get 0 results. I usually refresh Sunday after Stack Exchange Data Dump.